# I wonder why $E(G)$ must be the edge set of $G$. ("Graph Theory Fourth Edition" by Robin J. Wilson.)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, vector-spaces

I am reading "Graph Theory Fourth Edition" by Robin J. Wilson.

> Exercise 2.15:
> If $G$ is a simple graph with edge-set $E(G)$, the vector space of $G$ is the vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of integers modulo $2$, whose elements are subsets of $E(G)$. The sum $E+F$ of two subsets $E$ and $F$ is the set of eges in $E$ or $F$ but not both, and scalar multiplication is defined by $1.E=E$ and $0.E=\varnothing$. Show that this defines a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and find a basis for it.

I wonder why $E(G)$ must be the edge set of $G$.
I think we can construct the vector space even if we replace $E(G)$ with an arbitrary finite set $E$.

Comment: Do you mean replace $E(G)$ with an arbitrary finite subset of the set of edges of $G$?

Comment: @AirMike thank you very much for your comment. No. I mean replace $E(G)$ with any finite set $E$ whose element is not an edge of a graph.

Comment: $E$ may be $\{apple, orange, grape\}$.

Comment: I think this exercise can be an exercise in a linear algebra book in which the author doesn't write about graph theory at all.

Comment: You are completely right. However this specific case comes up naturally in graph theory and has some applications there, so very likely that's why it was used as an illustrative example.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right! This construction can be carried on in a more general setting.

Let $X$, $Y$ be sets. Recall that the *symmetric difference between $X$ and $Y$* is the set $X \triangle Y$ defined by
$$X \triangle Y := (X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap Y).$$

Given any set $X$, the symmetric difference $\triangle$ induces a binary operation on the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Note that $\triangle$ would be the binary operation $+$ that is described on the exercise if it was defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

One can prove that $(\mathcal{P}(X),\triangle)$ is an abelian group (this is half way to prove that we have a vector space). It remains to prove that the scalar multiplication described satisfies the required axioms for a vector space (and this straightforward).

Comment: Air Mike, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You’re very welcome! :)